# Print class function

Tags: python

I created a class function, but when I print the printing outcomes are all sticking together, how can I separate them?

```
class Article(object):
"""repersent an article"""

def __init__(self,title = "",year = 0,author = "",page = 0,price = 0):
    """everything that might be conclude in an article"""
    self._title = title
    self._year = year
    self._author = author
    self._page = page
    self._price = price

def getTitle(self):
    """Returns the article's title"""
    return self._title

def getYear(self):
    """Returns the article's publish year"""
    return self._year

def getAuthor(self):
    """Returns the article's author"""
    return self._author

def getPage(self):
    """Returns the article's page"""
    return self._page

def __str__(self):
    return str(self._title) + str(self._year) + str(self._author) + str(self._page) + str(self._price)


b = Article("pyomo",2016,"Marcel",354,40.99)
print(b)
```

**the printing outcome of this code is**:
pyomo2016Marcel35440.99

**What i want is something like this**:
pyomo, 2016, Marcel, 354, 40.99

**something like this will be even better**:

- Title: pyomo
- Year: 2016
- Author: Marcel
- Page: 354
- Price: 40.99

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: ```string formatting```.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Please refer to a tutorial on string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You never add any newlines in you string. You simple concatenate them together. Try something like this with python 3.6 and newer:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self._title}\n{self._year}\n{self._author}\n{self._page}\n{self._price}"
```

For older pyhton somthing like this could work fine:

```
def __str__(self):
    props = [self._title, self._year, self._author, self._page, self._price]
    return "\n".join(str(p) for p in props)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.6 or greater, you could use an f-string to great effect:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self._title}, {self._year}, {self._author}, {self._page}, {self._price}"
```

or, for the "even better" version (in a [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant fashion):

```
def __str__(self):
    return (
        f"Title: {self._title}\n"
        f"Year: {self._year}\n"
        f"Author: {self._author}\n"
        f"Page: {self._title}\n"
        f"Price: {self._price}"
    )
```

Read more about f-strings [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Answer (score 0):

Modify `__str__` like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"Title: {str(self._title)}\nYear: {str(self._year)}\nAuthor: {str(self._author)}\nPage: {str(self._page)}\nPrice: {str(self._price)}"
```

Note that f-strings were introduced in python 3.6, otherwise use `.format()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **string embedding** using `%s`:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (self._title, self._year, self._author, self._page, self._price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying `print (b.__dict__)`?
It returns a dictionary of your arguments:

`{'_title': 'pyomo', '_year': 2016, '_author': 'Marcel', '_page': 354, '_price': 40.99}`